# How can we change/check the frequency of evaluation of a budget Alert in Azure

Tags: azure

I have set up a budget alert using Azure Portal ,I have defined my budget as 400$ and frequency as 120$ .I have received the alert notification by mail .But my concern here is ,that in alert mail the actual value is 240 which is much more than 120 . I want the alert to be triggered right immediately when the value goes above 120(Threshold Value) .

Is there any approach where I can change/check the Frequency of evaluation of Budget Alert defined .

Answer (score 0):

Azure usage data is not updated in real-time
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-cost-mgt-data#cost-and-usage-data-updates-and-retention

I don't think there is an option to increase the evaluation frequency of the Alert. Even if you could do it, the cost data would be still delayed.